# How do I create a CanvasJS Chart using JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvasjs

I created a test chart and it works fine. I would like to fetch my data via ajax rather than embedding in the web page. I figure that I need to format my dataPoints arrays ( `{ x: new Date(2009, 0), y: 15 },`) so that they can be used in an external JSON file. In my example the format of the data that populates my chart is:

[My JSChart Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1001/qx1uguod/)

```
{
  name: "File Sharing",
  showInLegend: true,
  type: "stackedColumn100",
  color: "#4192D9 ",
  indexLabel: "{y}",
  dataPoints: [
    { x: new Date(2009, 0), y: 15 },
    { x: new Date(2010, 0), y: 15 },
    { x: new Date(2011, 0), y: 12 },
    { x: new Date(2012, 0), y: 10 },
    { x: new Date(2013, 0), y: 12 },
    { x: new Date(2014, 0), y: 10 }
  ]
},
```

I looked on the Canvas JS site and they used the following Ajax call example:

```
var dataPoints = [];
$.getJSON("https://canvasjs.com/services/data/datapoints.php?xstart=1&ystart=10&length=100&type=json", function(data) {  
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        dataPoints.push({x: value[0], y: parseInt(value[1])});
    });
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
        title:{
            text:"Rendering Chart with dataPoints from External JSON"
        },
        data: [{
        type: "line",
            dataPoints : dataPoints,
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
});
```

Not sure if this makes a difference but the format of the JSON data that is used in the AJAX call above is:

`[[1,12],[2,7],[3,6],[4,6],[5,9],[6,13],[7,12],[8,15],[9,14],[10,18]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**
https://jsfiddle.net/uvac6rdz/2/
with edited data format to match OP's preferred axisX.

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Composition of Internet Traffic in North America",
    horizontalAlign: "right"
  },
  axisX: {
    tickThickness: 0,
    interval: 1,
    intervalType: "year"
  },
  animationEnabled: true,
  toolTip: {
    shared: true
  },
  axisY: {
    lineThickness: 0,
    tickThickness: 0,
    interval: 20
  },
  legend: {
    verticalAlign: "center",
    horizontalAlign: "left"
  },

  data: [
  {
    name: "Real-Time",
    showInLegend: true,
    type: "column",
    color: "#004B8D ",
    indexLabel: "{y}",
    dataPoints: [
    { x: new Date(2009,0), y: 12 },
    { x: new Date(2010,0), y: 7 },
    { x: new Date(2011,0), y: 6}, 
    { x: new Date(2012,0), y: 6}, 
    { x: new Date(2013,0), y: 9}, 
    { x: new Date(2014,0), y: 13}, 
    { x: new Date(2015,0), y: 12}, 
    { x: new Date(2016,0), y: 15}, 
    { x: new Date(2017,0), y: 14}
    ]
  },

  ]
});

chart.render();
```

I changed the following:

1. the type on your `axisX.intervalType` from `"year"` to `"number"`
   (due to your sample data).
2. formatted your sample data from `[[1,12],[2,7]...` to follow
   `[{x: 1, y: 12}, {x: 2, y: 7},...`
3. chart type from `stackedColumn100` to `column`.

Looking at the documentation for canvasJS, the sample requires you to format the data to be following:
`{x: valueX, y: valueY}`

Comment: This worked well for me and makes sense. But what if I would like to use dates in my JSON file? Currently my Json file is similar to `[[1,12],[2,7],[3,6]]` I would like to use dates something similar to `[[2009,0,12],[2010,0,7],[2011,0,6]]` When I use dates a decimal point is added because my JSON reads as a number

Comment: Is it possible for me to still use the following format in my JSON file. `{ x: new Date(2009, 0), y: 15 }...` I figure if I do so I may need to convert my "x" data points to dates? `var dataPoints = json.map(function (p) {
    p.x = new Date(p.x);
    return p;
});` ?

Comment: Yeah that's fine, you'll need to also change the acidic type to date (like year)

Comment: @ Denis Tsoi Thanks

Comment: @ Denis Tsoi Sure. Thanks again!

Comment: can you please check my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401860/canvas-js-data-sampling-in-php) related to canvasjs?